# mysql: inserting data and autoincrement

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access

i am converting from access to mysql

i have a table in access where one of the columns is an autonumber

when i transfer the data into the mysql database (where i also have a column that is auto_increment), should i be transfering the auto_increment data into the auto_increment column, or will it auto_increment itself?

how do i ensure that if i do not transfer the autoincrement data from access, that it auto_increments properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to retain the autoincremented number, simply don't insert into that field.  It will increment itself.

But in all likelihood you'd *want* to keep it (if it wasn't being used, why is it there?), and with MySQL (unlike some other systems like SQL Server) you **can** insert values into autoincrement columns without having to set any options to enable doing so.

Comment: You can insert values into SQL Server for things like data imports when you have an identity column. I do it all the time when moving large anmounts of legacy data.

Comment: You can, but you have to set `IDENTITY_INSERT`.  I meant without setting any options, so I've updated the post to clarify.